# What are the use-cases for Aria-Expanded without Aria-Controls

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

Im curious if there are use cases for using the [aria-expanded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-expanded) attribute without the use of aria-controls.

Are there ways to 'self-declare' per say that the state of a node (lets say, a button) has changed using this attribute? If so:

- Does this only work for indicating that the button is visible or not?
- Can 'expanded' represent just a state change for the node?

I'm also a little bit hazy on all the uses for aria-expanded as the documentation seems to not be very solid. Is it just for declaring visibility of self and or controls? Can it indicate a state change rather than visibility change?

Any educating on this attribute would be greatly appreciated.

I have read a whole bunch of articles and blogposts on the aria-expanded attribute and still am not sure if use of the attribute without controls is valid or not, and what the contexts for such use being valid are.

Comment: Specifically this article has me confused: https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/sensible-aria-usage/expanded/ 

He is using aria-expanded on a button that toggles on and off a div with the id of "tooltip" but never connects the two. I am not understanding how that is beneficial/the connection is made.

Answer (score 1):

The `aria-expanded` attribute is meant to be set on a **operating** element that controls the visibility of a **controlled** element (which id is the value of `aria-controls`; *e.g. "this button controls this div"*). It allows assistive technologies to indicate their users that some content is available as a result of operating the button.

See this example of [an accordion](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/examples/accordion/). And this is me using Voice Over:

[image]

So to answer your question I don't think there is any. You have no reason to say that something is expanded if there's nothing else to show. If what you wanted was to indicate that a toggle is on or off, then `aria-pressed` seems a more appropriate option.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I thought, however I keep seeing the attr used without any references and don't see the point. Even in seemingly credible documentation: https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/sensible-aria-usage/expanded/

Comment: @NickKnack13 That was a surprise to me too. They seem to be a testing lab so they may be focusing on what assistive technologies actually do and worry less about what the specs say. I know that support for accessibility varies greatly amongst providers. Perhaps `aria-expanded` works as a substitute to `aria-pressed`?

Comment: That seems to be the case (based on how people are using it), but there is really not great documentation on that use-context if so, which is what I'm trying to get to the bottom of. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: `aria-expanded` (which is solid and reliable) does not require the presence of `aria-controls` and there is good reason to believe that `aria-controls` doesn't actually do anything genuinely useful. It should only be included for the sake of "lip service" to the standard. I don't think ATs handle it very consistently, or even at all. Have a read of this: https://heydonworks.com/article/aria-controls-is-poop/